# What's the preferred way of adding Azure user assigned identities into pods in AKS?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I've been working with EKS and GKE and in both places they have a formal, streamlined manner of ensuring a pod comes up with the necessary credentials for a "role" in the cloud's rbac system (IAM Role for AWS, Service Account in GCP) via K8's native service accounts. This makes integration with other of the host cloud's services quite easy. I'm now trying to do the same in AKS but I don't see any such integration for their respective rbac. Am I missing something badly? How do you do it?

Comment: you mean this? [Control access to cluster resources using Kubernetes role-based access control and Azure Active Directory identities in Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-ad-rbac)

Comment: No that's the other direction. I want a ServiceAccount in Kubernetes to be attached to a service principal or user assigned identity so that pods with it come with the credentials ready to access Aure (not K8s) resources. So for example, in EKS by adding the annotation "eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn" in the service account (and doing some configuration on the AWS IAM side) all pods with that service account will be injected with credentials to act as that iam role.

Comment: I'm working on a solution now. I'll update when I've completed.